# generating permalink with resources rather than id in rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is there a simple way of making rails routes to generate urls with permalink rather than id
what i mean is ..

```
resources :posts #=> generates urls like posts/12, posts/45/edit, ...
```

which can be used in controller as ***find(params[:id])***

now with

```
def to_param
  self.permalink
end
```

urls become **/posts/what-is-rails, /posts/what-is-rails/edit**,
now to find the record with permalink we still have to do

***find_by_permalink(params[:id])***

Now the question is, is there a easier way to generate urls with permalink in them

Answer (score 1):

Use [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem as seen at [#314 Pretty URLs with FriendlyId](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) Railscast.